# libxml2 HTML parsing

Tags: html, c, html-parsing, libxml2

I'm parsing HTML with libxml2, using XPath to find elements. Once I found the element I'm looking for, how can I get the HTML as a string from that element (keeping in mind that this element will have many child elements). Given a document:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Some document</title>
    </header

    <body>
        <p id="faq">
            Some kind of text <a href="http://www.nowhere.com/">here</a>.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Say I retrieved the `body` element with XPath and then get the HTML for that, I'd like to end up with a string containing:

```
<body>
    <p id="faq">
        Some kind of text <a href="http://www.nowhere.com/">here</a>.
    </p>
</body>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the purpose of [`xmlNodeDump`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump):

EDIT:

When you have a `xmlNodePtr` `node`, do something like:

```
xmlBufferPtr nodeBuffer = xmlBufferCreate();
xmlNodeDump(nodeBuffer, doc, node, 0, 1);
// ... Do something with nodeBuffer->content
// When done:
xmlBufferFree(nodeBuffer);
```

The 4th and 5th parameters control indentation and formatting.